# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cucumber-messages"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, rubymine, gherkin

I am trying to update gem gherkin from 5.1.0 to 9.0.0 but any version higher than 5.1.0 invokes this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "cucumber-messages":
  In GemFile:
    cucumber (= 4.1.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      cucumber-messages (>= 12.2.0, ~> 12.2) x64-mingw32

    gherkin (= 9.0.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 9.0.0, which depends on
      cucumber-messages (>= 8.0.0, ~> 8.0) x64-mingw32

Process finished with exit code 6
```

This is what I have in my gemfile

```
gem "cucumber", "4.1.0"
gem "cucumber-messages", "12.2.0"
gem "gherkin", "9.0.0"
gem "page-object"
gem "debase"
gem "selenium-webdriver"
gem "watir"
gem "watir-dom-wait", "0.3.3"
gem "watir-scroll", "0.3.0"
gem "webdriver-user-agent"
gem "webdrivers"
gem "require_all"
gem "rspec"
gem "faker"
gem "fig_newton"
gem "pretty_face"
gem "ffi"
gem "colorize"
gem "activesupport"
gem "rake"
```

Can anyone offer any help on how to resolve please

Thanks

Kev

Comment: Also my ruby version is 2.6.5p114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fixed some gems at certain versions, like *cucumber* and *cucumber-messages*. This can mean that dependencies between gems cannot be resolved.

You can drop problem causing fixed version numbers one by one until bundle succeeds.

Start by removing the version number for cucumber-messages.

Comment: OK, if I remove all versions thus and delete gemlock  
gem "cucumber"                     
gem "cucumber-messages" 
gem "gherkin" 

I get  
Using cucumber 2.2.0
Using cucumber-messages 8.0.0
Using gherkin 9.0.0

So, gherkin good but old version of cucumber

Comment: Next thus and delete gemlock  
gem "cucumber"  
gem "cucumber-messages", "8.0.0"  
gem "gherkin", "9.0.0"  
  
I get   
Using cucumber 2.2.0  
Using cucumber-messages 8.0.0  
Using gherkin 9.0.0

Comment: Next thus and delete gemlock
gem "cucumber", "4.1.0"
gem "cucumber-messages"
gem "gherkin"

I get
Using cucumber-messages 12.2.0
Using cucumber 4.1.0
Using gherkin 5.1.0

So this time cucumber is good but gherkin has reverted to a older version  
  
Now very confused

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, it is up to you: do you rather have a new cucumber ( which uses gherkin 5.1.0), or a newer gherkin? You have to compare the releasenotes to make a choice between those two. If you insist to use gherkin 9.0, because it has features you want to try out, then you're stuck with the cucumber it depends on.

Comment: By the way, I saw that in the last case gherkin 5.1.0 was used and  cucumber-gherkin 14.0.1..... I don't know exactly what that means, but maybe is your target of gherkin 9.0.0 not the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, like you say a choice to make.